# Trying to filter tag cloud args, but it removes the wrapper

Tags: widgets, tags

I'm trying to reset the font size for tag cloud by using the [`widget_tag_cloud_args`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_tag_cloud_args) filter as follows:

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'filter_tag_cloud_widget' );
function filter_tag_cloud_widget() {
    $args = array(
        'smallest'  => 16,
        'largest'   => 16,
        'unit'      => 'px'
    );
    return $args;
}
```

This should set the font size for all the tags to 16px. The code does its job, but now there is an issue. The `<div class="tagcloud"> ... </div>`wrapper for tag cloud is gone. The anchors are directly output in the sidebar like this:

```
<a href="/tag-path/" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-32 tag-link-position-2" style="font-size: 16px;" aria-label="tag">tag</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the defaults passed to the filter, one of which is `echo`, which is `false` by default for the widget. This is because the function that generates the tag cloud has `echo` equal to `true` by default, so your tag cloud is getting immediately output instead of `return`ed back to the widget handler.